# Manual selection input date to max returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, date, datepicker

I have two datepickers with max and min set. If for From date max is set as a particular date and I select that date manually it returns invalid date. Selecting any other date returns correct value.(Eg- If max set is 24th Oct and I select it manually then it returns undefined)

```
 <div class="col-sm-2">
  <h6>From Date</h6>
    <input type="date" onkeydown="return false" id="fromDate" class="form-control" ng-change="fdateSel()" max="{{fmaxdate}}" ng-model="fromDate">    
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-2">
   <h6>To Date</h6>
   <input type="date" onkeydown="return false" id="toDate" class="form-control" ng-change="tdateSel()" min="{{tmindate}}" max="{{tmaxdate}}" ng-model="toDate">
 </div>
```

Here is the controller

```
$scope.fromDate = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() - 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 7);
$scope.toDate = new Date();

$scope.fmaxdate = $filter('date')(new Date($scope.toDate.valueOf() - 1000 * 3600 * 24), "yyyy-MM-dd");
$scope.tmindate = $filter('date')(new Date($scope.fromDate.valueOf() + 1000 * 3600 * 24), "yyyy-MM-dd");
$scope.tmaxdate = $filter('date')(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd");

$scope.fdateSel = function () {
        $scope.tmindate = $filter('date')(new Date($scope.fromDate.valueOf() + 1000 * 3600 * 24), "yyyy-MM-dd");
    }

$scope.tdateSel = function () {
        if (undefined != $scope.toDate)
        $scope.fmaxdate = $filter('date')(new Date($scope.toDate.valueOf() - 1000 * 3600 * 24), "yyyy-MM-dd");
    }
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @MisterMystery since i am trying to get valueOf it logs value of undefined.. nothing else

Comment: Which line throws that error?

Comment: @MisterMystery when i select the date ng-change triggers fdateSel() and error throws up $scope.tmindate = $filter('date')(new Date($scope.fromDate.valueOf() + 1000 * 3600 * 24), "yyyy-MM-dd");

Answer (score 0):

The way we set the value to model matters.

Change this from:

```
$scope.fromDate = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() - 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 7);
$scope.toDate = new Date();
```

To:

```
$scope.fromDate = (() => {
  let fromDate = new Date(new Date().valueOf() - 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 7);
  fromDate = new Date(
    fromDate.getFullYear(),
    fromDate.getMonth(),
    fromDate.getDate()
    );
  return fromDate;
})();

$scope.toDate = (() => {
  let toDate = new Date();
  toDate = new Date(toDate.getFullYear(), toDate.getMonth(), toDate.getDate());
  return toDate;
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

I wasn't able to replicate the error you were seeing but I did notice you are missing the `ng-model` attributes in the inputs. Let me know if this helps.

Below is a working example:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller('exampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.fromDate = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() - 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 7);
  $scope.toDate = new Date();

  $scope.fmaxdate = new Date($scope.toDate.valueOf() - 1000 * 3600 * 24);
  $scope.tmindate = new Date($scope.fromDate.valueOf() + 1000 * 3600 * 24);
  $scope.tmaxdate = new Date();

  $scope.fdateSel = function () {
         if (undefined != $scope.fromDate) {
          $scope.tmindate = new Date($scope.fromDate.valueOf() + 1000 * 3600 * 24);
         }
      }

  $scope.tdateSel = function () {
          if (undefined != $scope.toDate) {
            $scope.fmaxdate = new Date($scope.toDate.valueOf() - 1000 * 3600 * 24);
            }
      }
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="exampleController as ctrl">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <h6>From Date</h6>
    <input type="date" onkeydown="return false" ng-model="fromDate" id="fromDate" class="form-control" ng-change="fdateSel()" max="{{fmaxdate}}">    
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
   <h6>To Date</h6>
   <input type="date" onkeydown="return false" ng-model="toDate" id="toDate" class="form-control" ng-change="tdateSel()" min="{{tmindate}}" max="{{tmaxdate}}">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I do have the ng-model in inputs

Comment: @MrinmoyDas Sorry I didn't realize you did have the `ng-model` attributes. But it does look like for `fromDate` you have a typo: `ngmodel` needs to be `ng-model`.

Comment: You need to handle the clear/delete date case where $scope.fromDate is null in fdateSel.